# My script for Double clicking, Pasting, Enter then Looping isn't working

Tags: loops, copy, paste, enter

How do I make a script that in order

- Double Left Clicks
- Then
- Pastes from Clipboard (Like CTRL+V)
- Then
- Presses Enter
- Then
- Loops over and over.

I tried but it doesn't work.

```
+LButton::
send {LButton 2}
Return
Send %clipboard%
send {Enter}
Loop 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with **Batch Programming**.

However, there are many tools available. Make use of Auto-IT to easily achieve this in seconds. I use this very often. **[Auto-IT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)**